# getting value of drop downlist when related form saved

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

`ciscacl` have `form1` and `juniper` have `form2`.

If I select `ciscoacl` I am getting `form1` and if enter data and save that `form1` successfully saved but after if I see the UI I am getting form 1 and `ciscoacl` in dropdown list it is ok but in case `juniper`,
if I select `juniper` I am getting `form2` and enter data and save that `form2` successfully saved but after save if I see the UI I am getting form 2 but dropdown value is `ciscoacl` I want `juniper` here.

```html
<div class="control-group">
    <label for="jaclMode" class="control-label">fwtype</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <select data-rel="chosen" id="jaclMode">
            <option value="CISCOACL">CISCOACL</option>
            <option value="JUNIPER">JUNIPER</option>
            <option value="IPFW">IPFW</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="newtab" id="formdiv">
    <form class="form-horizontal" action="/settings" method="POST" id="jacl">
        <div class="control-group">
            <label for="connectionMode" class="control-label">Connection Mode</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <select data-rel="chosen" id="connectionMode">
                    <option value="SSH">SSH</option>
                    <option value="Telnet">TELNET</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label for="switchIP" class="control-label">Switch IP Address</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" value="" id="switchIP" class="input-xlarge focused" data-trigger="change" data-regexp="^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$">
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Can you provide your Rails code please? IE your `.erb` file corresponding to the view above? Also, can you be more specific on what you're asking for?